# Comparing two lists of strings .CSV

Tags: python, csv, intersection

I'm trying to write  a script to compare two lists of strings from different spreadsheets and to print off a list of strings common to both spreadsheets. I'm a total novice, but so far I've got:

```
import csv
f1 = file("KaySinTan09.csv", "r")
f2 = file("Khanna11.csv", "r")

c1=csv.reader(open('KaySinTan09.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
c2=csv.reader(open('Khanna11.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')

output = c1.intersection(c2)
print output
```

I get an error saying "AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'intersection'".

Any advice on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: check out the diff command in linux.

Answer (score 2):

csv.reader is not a set, you need to convert it to one in order to do this:

```
c1= set(csv.reader(open('KaySinTan09.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|'))
c2 = set(csv.reader(open('Khanna11.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|'))

output = c1.intersection(c2)
print output
```

Answer (score 0):

`csv.reader` does not return a list - it returns a CSV reader object - so the `.intersection` method will not work. Maybe this will:

```
c1=csv.reader(open('KaySinTan09.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
c2=csv.reader(open('Khanna11.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')

c1_list = []
c2_list = []

for c in c1:
  c1_list.append(c)
for c in c2:
  c2_list.append(c)

output = set(c1_list).intersection(set(c2_list))
print output
```

This is not tested.

Comment: -0.  Wordy solution creates list inefficiently then creates set from list rather than creating set to begin with.